# Complex bandpass filter giving quadrature signal

Tags: filter-design, hilbert-transform, quadrature

I have found a technique detailed on page 34 & 35 of [this thesis](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/20158/master_Thuillier_Etienne_2016.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

In this, the author states a complex bandpass filter can be derived by first making a prototype real valued IIR filter, then setting the complex conjugate poles equal to each other. He then states the resulting complex filter will have a quality factor half that of the real valued one but the same centre frequency. The resulting filter is then more efficient than a combination of bandpass filter + Hilbert transform.

I can find no reference to this technique anywhere! Can anyone point me towards a reference explaining the mathematical concepts of this or an example of it's implementation so I can understand it better? How would you rate this technique compared to a bandpass+hilbert transform, or is there an even better way? I am only looking to achieve a quadrature signal for further processing, in this case frequency shifting.

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but you might be interested in this list of methods to generate an analytic signal: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/153.php

Comment: Thanks I have seen that list and it seems an excellent summary, it doesn't cover this specific method though.

Comment: You do know the unit circle represents the digital frequency axis? If not, understanding that does make it very clear with observation of the pole placement how this approach creates a "single-side-band" filter similar to using real band pass filters and Hilbert transforms.

Comment: Yes I can visualize 'how' it was working (no negative frequency content as you said) but was curious as to why I could find no mention of it anywhere, it seems a much quicker method than most.